# Get qiskit-native gates from a circuit containing custom gates

Tags: qiskit

I have a custom gate in qiskit defined as follows:

```
sub_circuit = QuantumCircuit(3, name='toggle_cx')
sub_circuit.cx(0,1)
sub_circuit.cx(1,2)
sub_circuit.cx(0,1)
sub_circuit.cx(1,2)

toggle_cx = sub_circuit.to_instruction()
```

Say I add this to a `QuantumCircuit`:

```
qr = QuantumRegister(4)
new_qc = QuantumCircuit(qr)

new_qc.append(toggle_cx, [qr[1],qr[2],qr[3]])
```

Now, how do I get information about the qiskit-native gates that were used to make up this custom gate from the final `QuantumCircuit` object?
I tried printing the `QuantumCircuit` object dictionary; it gave the following output:

```
{'_ancillas': [],
 '_base_name': 'circuit',
 '_calibrations': defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {}),
 '_clbit_indices': {},
 '_clbits': [],
 '_control_flow_scopes': [],
 '_data': [(Instruction(name='toggle_cx', num_qubits=3, num_clbits=0, params=[]),
            [Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 1),
             Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 2),
             Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 3)],
            [])],
 '_global_phase': 0,
 '_layout': None,
 '_metadata': None,
 '_parameter_table': ParameterTable({}),
 '_parameters': [],
 '_qubit_indices': {Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 2): BitLocations(index=2, registers=[(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 2)]),
                    Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 3): BitLocations(index=3, registers=[(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 3)]),
                    Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 1): BitLocations(index=1, registers=[(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 1)]),
                    Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 0): BitLocations(index=0, registers=[(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 0)])},
 '_qubits': [Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 0),
             Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 1),
             Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 2),
             Qubit(QuantumRegister(4, 'q0'), 3)],
 'cregs': [],
 'duration': None,
 'name': 'circuit-4',
 'qregs': [QuantumRegister(4, 'q0')],
 'unit': 'dt'}
```

In this output, it labels the corresponding instruction as `toggle_cx` and not the qiskit-native gates.
I tried to use `new_qc.decompose()`, however, if my circuit had other gates like Hadamard or PauliX; it will decompose those gates too, into even more basic gates. I only want to see what gates is `toggle_cx` made up of.

Context: I'm trying to make custom qiskit backends, which will have access only to the `QuantumCircuit` object passed as a parameter.

Comment: Is this answers your question: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24540/9474 ?

Comment: you can decompose specify circuit with `decompose(gate_to_decompose='toggle_cx')`

Comment: Thank you, this helps.